# react js изменения обрабатываются после второго клика по чекбоксу

Tags: javascript, reactjs

[image: вот этот третий чекбокс]

Я хочу обработать нажатие этого чекбокса , как фильтр, чтобы билеты с 3-мя пересадками не выводились в списке
Вот JSX эллемента

```
<div className="InputRow">
        <input type="checkbox" id="threecheck" checked={this.props.transferCheck.threeCheck} onChange={this.handleThree}/>
        <label htmlFor="threecheck">3 пересадки</label>
 </div>
```

Обработчик

```js
handleThree=()=>{
//тут я использую метод из коннекта, чтобы передать false в редьюсер, ниже я вывожу значение чека в консоль
    this.props.check({
        threeCheck:document.getElementById("threecheck").checked
});
    if(!this.props.transferCheck.threeCheck){
        this.props.check({
            allCheck:false
        });
    }
    console.log(this.props.transferCheck);
    console.log(document.getElementById("threecheck").checked);
    this.props.setShowTickets(sortSlice(this.props.ticketReducer.allTickets,
        this.props.transferCheck,
        this.props.switchReducer.switch));
}
```

sortSlice заполняет и сортирует взависимости от кнопки (самый дешевый, самый быстрый) массив и передаем в действии в редьюсер, и там слайс делаем 5 эллементов.
как работает чек в коннекте

```
check: (checked) => {
                dispatch({
                    type: "CHECK_UNCHECK",
                    checks: checked
                });
            }
```

собственно редьюсер

```js
const initialState = {
    allCheck: true,
    withoutCheck: true,
    oneCheck: true,
    twoCheck: true,
    threeCheck: true
};

function transferCheck(state = initialState, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case "CHECK_UNCHECK":
            return Object.assign({}, state, action.checks);

    }
    return state;

}

export default transferCheck;
```

Изначально, все галочки стоят. Когда я снимаю галочку с того последнего чекбокса, смотрим консоль.
[image: первое нажатие]
первое - это контейнер с состояниями чекбоксов, которые не изменились, и ниже значение чекбокса через js. threeCheck должен был измениться, но этого не произошло. нажимаем еще раз
[image: второй клик]

После второго клика почему-то все же изменилось состояние. Почему?

Comment: Видимо потому что изменение состояния асинхронно. Вы вызываете метод `check` из пропс, внутри этого метода через диспатчер дергается экшн, который обрабатывается в редьюсере, однако метод, откуда вы всё это вызвали `handleThree` совершенно законно может не знать, что что-то обновилось в пропсах, потому что для него еще всё осталось прежним. Я бы такую проверку засунул куда-то типо `mapStateToProps`. Ваши сайд эффекты ожидаемы. Разделите логику метода `handleThree`, либо юзайте коллбэки.

Comment: @DenisBubnov спасибо за ответ, но меня все же интересует, почему диспатчится асинхронно, ведь я не использую никаких redux-thunk. В документации пишется, что dispatch изначально синхронен.

Comment: да-да, он синхронен, а вот изменение состояния асинхронно, отсюда и вылазит подводный камень. Изменение состояиния, а также пропсов асинхронно, то есть если вызвать `setState` и сразу вывести после этого значение из стейта, то Вы не увидите там значения, которое туда положили, для его просмотра вторым параметром у `setState` можно передать колбэк функцию, внутри которой уже гарантированно будет установленное значение.

Answer (score 0):

Самый лучший вариант - не использовать стейт. Вообще. Зачем он для чекбоксов? Это настолько раздуто и избыточно в 99% случаев, что хочется рвать волосенки на голове каждый раз, когда кто-то это использует. К счастью, React предоставляет uncontrolled inputs, чем я вам и рекомендую воспользоваться. Поскольку каждый раз, когда для таких компонентов используется стейт, означает, что данные сохраняются для последующей обработки, а последующая обработка в 99% случаев - отправка формы или иные ее события.

Но конечно, если при щелчку на чекбокс надлежит вызвать какое-то событие, без коллбэка не обойтись. Алексей Николаев src -- https://qna.habr.com/q/648393